# Re-Use Color codes in resouce.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is it possible to duplicate colors in xaml?

I have the following:

```
<Color x:Key="Main_Color_1">Red</Color>
```

Now I want to reuse this color in more specific color declarations for example:

```
<Color x:Key="MainView_Color_TopBar">[Red]</Color>
```

But instead of defining Red again I would like to reuse the Main_Color_1.
Here some code, I tested but failed:

```
<Color x:Key="MainView_Color_TopBar">{StaticResource Main_Color_1}</Color>
<Color x:Key="MainView_Color_TopBar" A={Binding A, Source={StaticResource Main_Color_1}}></Color>
```

I know I could define Brushes and set the color there, but if possible I would like to define colors aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is a Color supposed to be able "reuse" another Color? A Color is a Color and System.Windows.Media.Color is a value type (struct) that gets copied by value. It cannot be based on another Color object.

You could reuse a Color in several different Brushes but that's it:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="brush" Color="{StaticResource Main_Color_1}" />
```

Comment: just hoped there is some way

Comment: There isn't. At least not in XAML. You can't bind the A, B, G, R, ... properties of a Color resource because these are not dependency properties.

Comment: what I found out is that I can apply staticresouce to A, B, G, R but than I would need to split the color codes into those 4 values which is rather annoying so it would look like <sys:Single x:Key="A">255</sys:Single> now again for B, G, R and the color blocks would be <Color x:Key="Main_Color_1" A={StaticResource A} /> that compiles but its ugly to have 4 Singles for every color and when reusing have to specify those 4 staticresources again

Comment: This is a quite awful solution If you ask me. Then you might be better of defining the Color resource programmatically instead of defining them in the XAML markup.

Comment: totally agree with you